# Displaying data to a map, creating a choropleth

Tags: visualization, choropleth, gis

What I would like to do is create a choropleth map which is darker or lighter based on the number of data points in a particular area.

I have the following data:

```
RO-B, 9
PL-MZ, 24
SE-C, 3
DE-NI, 5
PL-DS, 14
ES-CM, 11
RO-IS, 2
DE-BY, 51
SE-Z, 18
CH-BE, 10
PL-WP, 1
ES-IB, 1
DE-BW, 21
DE-BE, 24
DE-BB, 1
IE-M, 26
ES-PV, 1
DE-SN, 6
CH-ZH, 31
ES-GA, 1
NL-GE, 2
IE-U, 1
ES-AN, 4
FR-J, 82
DE-HH, 34
PL-PD, 1
PL-LD, 6
GB-WLS, 60
GB-ENG, 8619
RO-BV, 45
CH-VD, 2
PL-SL, 1
DE-HE, 17
SE-I, 1
HU-PE, 4
PL-MA, 4
SE-AB, 3
CH-BS, 20
ES-CT, 31
DE-TH, 25
IE-C, 1
CZ-ST, 1
DE-NW, 29
NL-NH, 3
DE-RP, 9
CZ-PR, 4
IE-L, 134
HU-BU, 10
RO-CJ, 1
GB-NIR, 29
ES-MD, 33
CH-LU, 11
GB-SCT, 172
CH-GE, 3
BE-BRU, 30
BE-VLG, 25
```

It references the `ISO3166-2` of a country and sub region, and the # corresponds to the amount of data points affiliated with that region.

I've seen [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/esosedi/regions) which seems to also use the same `ISO3166-2` to reference countries.

I'm trying to figure out how I could modify their code to display my data points, such that if the number is higher the area would be darker, if the number is less it would be lighter.

It seems it should be possible, the first thing I was trying to do was modify this [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/9o9ak7fb/17/), which seems to be very close to what I need, but I couldn't get it to work.

For instance this line:

```
osmeRegions.geoJSON('RU-MOW',
```

Seems to directly reference a `ISO3166-2` code, but it's not as simple as just changing that (or maybe it is but I couldn't get that to work properly).

Does anyone know if I could possibly adapt the code from that project to create the map rendering I've described?

Or perhaps there's a different way to achieve the same goal?